# How does decorator pattern work internally in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a question regrading the working of decorator pattern in C++. Consider the following scenario ( which I got from net. Sorry, I could not make the question smaller since I had to give all details.)

```
class print{
  public:
   virtual ~print(){};
   virtual void print_name() = 0;
};

//Actual base class which is to be used for printing. Has only name
class name:public print{
   public:
  //Destructor
  ~name() { cout << "destructing name" << endl; } 
  void print_name(){ 
    cout << "Ajay " << endl;
  }
 };

class decorator:public print{
   print *print_content;
       public:

   //constructor
   decorator(print* print_arg){
    print_content = print_arg;
   }

   //Destructor
   ~decorator() {
       if(print_content){
        delete print_content;
        print_content = NULL;
       }
    }

   void print_name(){
       print_content->print_name();
   }
   };

class surname:public decorator{
    public:

//Constructor
surname( print * print_arg ):decorator(print_arg) {}

//Destructor
   ~surname(){ 
    cout << "Destructing surname" << endl;
   }

   void print_name(){
    cout << " Bidari" << endl;
    decorator::print_name();
   }
    };

 class address:public decorator{
   public:
   address( print * print_arg):decorator(print_arg) {}
   ~address(){
       cout <<"Destructing address" << endl;
   }
   void print_name(){
    cout << "Bijapur" << endl;
    decorator::print_name();
   }
   };
```

All the classes have required semantics as required in a decorative design pattern.
The **main** function is as follows.

```
int main(){

    print * name_surname_address = new address(new surname(new name));
   name_surname_address->print_name();
}
```

The program prints the result as expected.

**OUTPUT**

```
 Bidari
Ajay

Bijapur
 Bidari
Ajay
```

I don't understand how the call lands in surname::print_name(). I mean the function calls

```
print * name_surname_address = new address(new surname(new name));
```

calls print_name of address which calls decorator::print_name() which in turn calls print::print_name().

Comment: `decorator::print_name()` doesn't call `print::print_name()`. `print::print_name()` is pure and the program would crash. `decorator::print_name()` actually calls `print_content->print_name()` which happens to be `surname::print_name()`.

Answer (score 2):

First you create the 'name' object. It will print "Ajay".
Then you pass that object as argument when creating a 'surname' object.
Surname object will create a 'decorator' that will remember the address of the 'name' (Ajay) - you inherited the decorator!!!
Surname also overrides the print function - it prints 'Bidari' and calls decorator::print_name();
Now you pass the 'surname' object as argument when creating an 'address' object.
The 'address' object will create a 'decorator' (again, you inherited the decorator) that will remember the address of the 'surname' (Bidari).
The 'address' also overrides the print function - it prints 'Bijapur' and calls decorator::print_name();

Or to explain it when you make the actual function call, you call print on the 'address' object.
It will print 'Bijapur' and it will call print on the 'surname' (decorator::print_name()), because you created the 'address' by passing the 'surname'. That will print 'Bidari'. The decorator::print_name() is called immediately after that and it prints the first one - 'Ajay'.

P.S.
If you find this explanation as not useful, I'll not blame you, because I find it heavy to read too :-)

Comment: The answer helped me understand. Thanks :)